# Cannot complete my Game Build checklist because of Store And Devcomp Packages Match error

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, steam, steamworks-api, depot

I have uploaded my 2 Builds on Steam, one for macOS and one for Windows, but the Depots section looks like this:

[image]

Here's my Builds settings:

[image]

And here's my Depots settings:

[image]

I have no idea about what to do to complete my Depot checklist in my Dashboard. I've read the official Documentation but found no help from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably already solved this by this point, but here's my answer for anyone facing this in the future.

To "fix" this issue, you need to understand something that Steam's tooltip for that entry does not tell you: the depots in your Store and Devcomp packages must match *exactly*, as in, they need to have the same depots.

This means that you either need to add the development depots to your Store package or, like I did, (temporarily) remove the development depots from your Devcomp package while your build is under review.

This will give you the green checkmark that you're looking for.

Comment: I just fixed my depots and it all works! Removed the default depot.

Answer (score 5):

This is very late, but it might help others.

From your app dashboard, go to:

```
All Associated Packages, DLC, Demos and Tools.
```

Under:

```
Promotional or special-use packages
```

select your package title and add/remove depots. Also change package name if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should use separate depots for each OS builds for binary executables... And common content files place in 3st shared content depot and include (add) it in both builds.

Comment: Thanks, I had 2 depots initially, one for Mac and one for Win, but still got the same issue.

Comment: It even says this error message for my soundtrack, which has its own depot.

Answer (score 1):

to solve this you just need to include all the folders into the directory.

Example:
Instead of game.exe
put mygamefolder/game.exe

Answer (score 0):

I can see on Your first screenshot that 1st condition in checklist for successful Game Build "Public Default Branch Includes 'Mystery Box.exe' " does'nt execute. You does'nt have default build branch (for Windows build) that contains binary executable with .exe extension for Windows OS. Your default build branch #7277404 "Public default branch" marked as  macOS depot. Maybe this is the source of Your problem.

Comment: Ok, but if I add the Win version to the Default Branch, the the macOS is out of it and cannot complete the last 2 options (Package includes Win and macOS Depot)

Comment: I think that You should make two separate packages (depots) for Windows and macOS.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that it seems like the field is case-sensitive. So "game.exe" had to be instead "Game.exe".